# Observable result is not working in template?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

My preloader code is:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private preloaderState$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  activate() {
    this.preloaderState$.next(true);
  }

  disactivate() {
    this.preloaderState$.next(false);
  }

  preloader(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.preloaderState$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Template is:

```
<div *ngIf="spinnerService.preloader() | async">Loading...</div>
```

Activation preloader is:

```
this.spinnerService.activate()
```

Why I dont get message Loading...?

Answer (score 0):

because it is not a queue at the moment of subscription it didn't replay all previous events

try BehaviorSubject instead it will hold last value for new subscribers

```
private preloaderState$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind method in view, it is called on every change detection trigger and every time you create new subscription to this Subject and wait for next state. Call this method once and attach to view.